# addClass in jquery doesn't work as I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a code that adds a class (`.class2`) using jQuery. The class is applied, but some styles of the class don't work :

```
$('.item1').addClass('class2');
```

```css
.item1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: -10px 0px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s;
    transition: background-color 0.4s;
}
.item1:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.class2 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: default;
    /* background-color and border aren't applied */
}
```

Comment: Add your full code please

Comment: Is that all your code? Does `item1` elements have another class?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Im testing your code and all work fine. look here : https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/1bjgkxq8/

Comment: I've solved the problem. Thanks for all answers

Comment: @GerryStudios hopefully your "solution" is not simply using `!important`

Comment: @jbmartinez its not necessary because all work fine.

Comment: I'm surprised, that the "use `!important`" answer was accepted... It's really bad practice...

Comment: @GerryStudios Take a look at my answer for a more complete explanation and why using `!important` is bad!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you load jquery library, and still doesn's work.
You can add !important to style so can ovveride the style, here is example of code at class2.

```
.class2 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) !important;
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    cursor: default !important;
    /* background-color and border aren't applied */
}
```

javascript jquery

Comment: !important isn't the solution for anything. It's just an workaround.
If the rules are not being applied, it's because they aren't specific enough.

Comment: Elias's point is that, while it works, it's not very good practice to use `!important`

Comment: How can this answer be accepted?? The use of `!important` is very bad practice...

Comment: I've posted a right solution for this, also an explanation of the problem.
The `!important` is just an work-around, or a quick-fix, but if you code using !important everywhere, in a few lines of code you will have a very, very bad css.

Answer (score 1):

That because `.item1` has already a `background-color` and override the new `background-color` added by new class `.class2`, so you could try to make your rule more specific like :

```
.item1.class2 {
   ...
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: !important isn't the solution for anything. It's just an workaround.
If the rules are not being applied, it's because they aren't specific enough.

Comment: @GerryStudios this may work, but is not an ideal solution at all. You should organise your rules correctly so they have the correct specificity. `!important` is a blunderbuss which causes more problems than it solves

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't on jQuery. The problem is with your CSS rules.

## Explanation

The browser always will apply the rule that is more specific, eg:

HTML:

```
<div id="my-div">
   <ul class="my-list">
      <li class="my-item">
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-div > ul > li.my-item {
    background-color: none;
}

.my-item {
    background-color: red
}
```

The browser will check what rule is more specific, in this case, the first one is clearly more specific.

If you want to override this rule, you must write a rule with at least the same specificity [(Check this specificity calculator)](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

If the rules have the exact same specificity, the last one will be applied.

## Solution

Use your browser developer tools to check what rule is being applied on your element, then write a rule with at least equal specificity.

There's no a exact solution, since the entire page should be analysed.

## Why not !important?

First let's understand how `!important` works. !important will make your rule have the highest specificity, like an "infinite" specificity.

So that rule only can be override for a rule after this one, also with !important.

**Okay, this works, solve my problem, right?**

Although this solve your problem right now, this practice isn't good, and will give you a very hard to maintain CSS.

If you use it on everything, you is just killing the `C` of `CSS` (Cascading Style Sheets), and you will need to rely only on rules orders, and sometimes you will just not be able to write a rule that you want.

Everyone that started using CSS thinks that the Cascade is a boring thing, that using !important on everything is fine, but isn't. Soon or later you will realize.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is working for me (see below). Check your developer console if you're styles are overwritten by other rules. In this case, use a **higher specifity**, e.g. `.item1.class2` to overwrite your already set background-color.

**`!important` isn't a solution**, but a workaround at best (it's bad practice). Try to organize your rules to have the proper order.

```js
// JS with jQuery
$('.item1').addClass('class2');
```

```css
.item1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin: -10px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s;
  transition: background-color 0.4s;
}
.item1:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.item1.class2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: default;
  /* background-color and border aren't applied */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1"></div>
```